# xpath match first and last child

Tags: php, html, xpath

Trying to determine if any P tag text's is entirely within strong/B tags

```
// Match (unacceptable, flag to user):
<p><strong>Any text and <span>maybe</span> other <em>tags</em></strong></p>
// Don't match (acceptable):
<p>Any text and <strong>maybe</strong> other <em>tags</em></p>
```

Comment: You can compare `string(//p)` and `string(//p/strong)`

Answer (score 1):

- Any `p` ...
  `//p`
- with at least one `strong` descendant node ...
  `//p[.//strong]`
- that has some text content other then just whitespaces ...
  `//p[.//strong[normalize-space(.) != ""]]`
- and no text node descendant with content that has no `strong` ancestor node:

  ```
  //p[
    .//strong[normalize-space(.) != ""] and 
    not(.//text()[normalize-space(.) != "" and not(ancestor::strong)])
  ]
  ```

This checks for two conditions. First that the paragraph has some actual content that is inside `strong` and that is has no actual content that has not inside a `strong` - in other word content that is formatted differently.

Example:

```php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<p><strong>Any text and <span>maybe</span> other <em>tags</em></strong></p>
<p>Any text and <strong>maybe</strong> other <em>tags</em></p>
<p><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong>tea</strong></p>
<p><em><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong> tea</strong></em></p>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = 
  '//p[
      .//strong[normalize-space(.) != ""] and 
      not(.//text()[normalize-space(.) != "" and not(ancestor::strong)])
    ]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $p) {
  var_dump(
    $document->saveXml($p)
  );
}
```

Output:

```php
string(75) "<p><strong>Any text and <span>maybe</span> other <em>tags</em></strong></p>" 
string(54) "<p><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong>tea</strong></p>" 
string(64) "<p><em><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong> tea</strong></em></p>"
```

The expression can be extended to cover `b` as well:

```
//p[
   (
     .//strong[normalize-space(.) != ""] or
     .//b[normalize-space(.) != ""]
   ) and 
   not(
     .//text()[
       normalize-space(.) != "" and 
       not(ancestor::*[self::strong or self::b])
     ]
   )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks that the P tag contains no text or other HTML tags before and after any Strong tags, determining that the P tag is entirely bold (strong).

```
$false_headings = $xpath->query("//p/strong");

foreach ($false_headings as $heading) {
    if ($heading->previousSibling === null and $heading->nextSibling === null) {
        // Report to user 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, partly based on @gangabass' suggestion. It counts the `<p>` elements that only contain a single `<strong>` element that are optionally only surrounded by whitespace text.

```php
$unacceptableNodesCount = $xpath->evaluate( 'count(//p[count(*) = 1 and name(*) = "strong" and normalize-space() = string(strong)])' );

var_dump( $unacceptableNodesCount );
```

---

To be honest though, if the goal is to prevent your users from using merely bold text and your users are determined, they'll probably find a way. For instance by surrounding the `<strong>` element with Unicode whitespace chars, or something similar.

Comment: It's not that the users are determined. Instead usually, lazy (or unaware). Web CMS uses TinyMCE text editor. User pastes their content from Word document, not actually using the correct heading tags, using bolded text for headings. I'm writing a SEO report for the given text. Flagging that the user should use the correct heading styles given by the TinyMCE editor rather than bolded paragraphs. A small section of bolded text within a paragraph is of course acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description suggests you also want to catch

```
<p><strong>Builder's</strong><strong> tea</strong></p>
```

and perhaps also

```
<p><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong>tea</strong></p>
```

which aren't caught by some of the suggested solutions.

But it's not clear whether you also want to catch

```
<p><emph><strong>Builder's</strong> <strong> tea</strong></emph></p>
```

I think the closest to "any P tag text's is entirely within strong/B tags" in XPath 2.0 is

```
//p[empty(.//text()[normalize-space()] except .//strong//text()])]
```

which selects all p elements having no non-white descendant text node that is not a descendant of a strong element within the p.

I can't immediately see a way of doing this in XPath 1.0, but my XPath 1.0 is very rusty.